# Could I define a string for execute select which column?

Tags: python, sqlite

| ID | Unit | gram | km |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | gram | 10 | 20 |
| 2 | km | 100 | 500 |

```
    con=sqlite3.connect(database='database.db')
    cur=con.cursor()
    try:
        cur.execute("SELECT ID,Unit FROM Product")
        rows=cur.fetchall()
        for row in rows:
            print(row[1])
            cur.execute("SELECT Unit,? FROM Product WHERE ID=?",(row[1],row[0],))
            rows2=cur.fetchall()
            print(rows2)
```

Could I define a string for execute select column? In my case, following the unit to define take which unit column and write to table.

Comment: It looks like you're missing a trailing quotation. Also, could you describe the expected output? It's not clear how the table is linked to the question at hand.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - but the string substitution available on the SQLite Python connector won't substitute column names: it is used just for data placeholders.

To use dynamic column or table names (or any other dynamism in the SQL syntax), just format the string using another mechanism prior to calling `cur.execute`.

For example, with f-strings:

```
    con=sqlite3.connect(database='database.db')
    cur=con.cursor()
    try:
        cur.execute("SELECT ID,Unit FROM Product")
        rows=cur.fetchall()
        for row in rows:
            print(row[1])
            #this will interpolate "row[1]" and then call execute to interpolate the ID value;
            cur.execute(f"SELECT Unit,{row[1]} FROM Product WHERE ID=?",(row[0],))
            rows2=cur.fetchall()
            print(rows2)
```

Just keep in mind that when using the SQL connector interpolation, it automatically escapes the data, voiding any attempts to do SQL injection. When you do interpolate the data before the call, you have to take care of that. Usually this data comes from a controlled environment, but if, for example, the column name comes from some untrusted input, you have to do the escaping yourself.